# What's the difference between MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer and Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate

Tags: c#, .net

as stated above I need to know what the difference is between this two possibilities when trying to pass a delegate as a callback to a native DLL. I sometimes have to use the first one and sometimes the second one for my code to work. However, it is unclear to me what's the difference and when to use which possibility.

Please enlighten me ;)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, `MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer` would be used when you have a `MethodInfo` object to start with. `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`, on the other hand, would be used when you have a delegate to begin with.